# How to hide rows in displaytag?

Tags: java, filter, displaytag

I have created a table using display tag library (version 1.1) and I'm filling it with values from a data base.
I do not want to show certain rows.
For example i only want to show the records that match a given string or regular expression.

Records retrieved from database :

```
foo
bar
string1
foo2
bar2
string2
```

Given filter : "foo"

Expected Result :

```
foo
foo2
```

Remarks 
- I need to filter a list of cached records, i can't apply the filter directly to the database query.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And why would you want your presentation layer to manage your business logic?

Comment: i know it's not the best approach, but i was given this task at work and refactoring the existing application would take too long.

Comment: if you're so constricted I guess you could always write a bit of JSP code `<% ... %>` to filter out the results you need into a new list, set this list as an attribute and use it as a data source for your `<display:table/>` instead of the list from the result set.

Comment: The problem is that i am facing a very large data set and i was wondering if there is a way to do it whitout caching another list. The filters may be too general in some cases, and that would practically duplicate the data set.

Comment: Write your own tag? You are in a very bad design territory, don't expect to get off easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want the Filters to work at client side only, without hitting the server, Try JQuery plugins. There are plenty of JQuery Plugins which does Sort and Filter/Search the Table or result sets.
2. If you want the Server to Deal with that, write a Custom Implementation for `org.displaytag.pagination.PaginatedList` interface, and add your own Filter method, which you can invoke based on your search/sort criteria. Please Note that, if you implement this interface, then your List should be of PaginatedList type only. Refer the Interface Spec and [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html) and [Display tag pagination problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888367/display-tag-pagination-problem) for details.