# External Paging example in display tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, external, paging, displaytag

I am a newbie in display tag. I am using display tag 1.2,struts2 and hibernate.
Display tags works great, except its fetching entire db row whenever i clicked on next page. I find out that I have to use external pagination of display tag. As I am a newbie, So any complete example of external pagination would be appropriated.

Comment: for example, If my pagesize 15 rows per page but display tag fetch all the rows from database. every time when i click on pagination number,it fetch all of the rows from db.

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888367/display-tag-pagination-problem .
The solution is there.

Comment: okay Swift...but does this solution work?

Comment: Not sure, but a good way to know it is to try...

Answer (score 0):

i have some problem  with paginatedList

> This is my previous hibernate method to show list on page

```
public List<TXT_Beans> regenerateListData(int cust_Id)
{
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
   String sqlQuery=null;
   List<TXT_Beans> txtList = new ArrayList<TXT_Beans>();

  try  
  {
   sqlQuery="select `accounts`.`account_id`,`customer_information`.`customer_unique_enroll_id`,`accounts`.`branch_id`,csp_information`.`bc_csp_code`,`csp_information`.`csp_alpha_id`,`customer_information`.`first_name`,from `customer_information` join `customer_accounts_xref` using (customer_unique_enroll_id) WHERE`customer_accounts_xref`.`customer_unique_enroll_id`="+cust_Id;
     session.beginTransaction();
```

............................
This was my previous query when display tag was fetching the entire row. Now How to modify this  for the situation where I have to fetch only specified no. of row instead the entire db using display tag ,no need to sort.

Comment: actually my problem is : 1) There is a txt file which has n no. of customers. so i have to iterate all customers one by one and based on customersId as a parameter i have to call above hibernate method to fetch all details of respective customers.  So problem is that how to provide external paging because i have to provide customerId to fetch details...any help would be appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

External paging is 4 step process.

1. Get the `total result count`, divide by page size and display the page numbers in UI.
2. Make the database call with `pageNumber` to retrieve the data along with the filter conditions if any from server component e.g your hibernate
3. In your server side  code, you have to retrieve record starting from `pagesize * pagenumber +1`  to `pagesize * (pagenumber+1)` and return back. This is referred as paged result.
4. Display the `paged result` return from step 3 in the UI with `pagenumber` selected.