# Paging in struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I need to implement a paging solution using **Struts2** for the client side display and **hibernate** as the persistence layer. Since my database has lots of records I need to load only specific amount of records at a given time (6 records per page) and show users paging numbers under the results table. When user clicks on a specific number I need to fetch the particular data from database and update it in the struts UI. [I can see many examples](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/paginationinstruts.html)
where it requires entire data list to create the display UI. Is there anyway that I can implement my requirement using this approach? If not can anyone tell me an example way of implementing this?

Comment: what are you using to display the paginated data? with `s:iterator` or some sort of plugin?

Comment: "for the client side display" you'll need to implement a service, is json sufficient or do you need xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding following attributes to the displaytag table. 
`partialList="true"` `size="resultSize"`. Here **resultSize** is the variable where you assign the total row count of the result inside the action class. [More information can be found here](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html)

Answer (score 1):

If u want to fetch only 6 results at a time, use:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from EntityName");
query.setMaxResults(6);
```

Also, for the UI u can use [displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html). It has inbuilt pagination feature. Also, it will fetch only 6 results at a time if u set pagesize="6" and set partialList="true". I guess, there is no need to use the setMaxResults() method also.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is not working. If I remove setMaxResults(6) then it loads each and every record.

Comment: oh forgot... u also need to set sort="external"
refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888367/display-tag-pagination-problem and answer by chanokim. Though the answer could have been much simpler, it still should work. The gist is u should implement PaginatedList and should use the 2 methods setMaxResults() and setFirstResult(). I have used displaytag only with jdbc & sql, without any trouble with pagination. Do reply how it went.

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate you can specify something like

```
if (offset >= 0) 
{
    query.setFirstResult(offset);
}
if (size > 0) 
{
    query.setMaxResults(size);
}
```

So as per page number click you can fetch that many records from the database.

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it in hibernate side. That is already implemented. I need to know how to display it using struts2 as asked in my question

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to indicate that the Hibernate side was already done and you tagged this question as Hibernate, so it seems fair that some people would try to tell you how to do it in Hibernate.