# Implementing External Paging and Sorting Using Display Tag In Struts2

Tags: mysql, struts2, displaytag

I need to know how to implement the **external paging** and **sorting method** of **displaytag** in **struts2**.

In the reference documentation, there is only jsp page information.

Further they provide that a class should implements the PaginatedList Interface for making the external paging and sorting.
Using the object of the **PaginatedList** implemented class, we can do the external Paging.

I tried the method that has been used in the following link  [Answer provided in the DispalyTag Pagination Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899850/1093784)

But the problem I am facing now is, after implementing the abstract methods of the PaginatedList ,

- How to use the object of the class to perform the external paging function?
- How to set the values for the methods?
- And how to retrieve the index and page numbers in action class?
- The object is not retrieved in the jsp page.showing error like size attribute is not defined.

I searched the internet, but I could not find any clear resources or examples.

Please help me to solve the problem.

I will be thankful if any good examples are provided and also suggestions.