# Hit query on pagination in display tag

Tags: mysql, jsp, pagination, struts2, displaytag

I use DisplayTag in my struts2 application and i want to hit query on clicking pagination.

Ex : When user click on the next page or any page then query is fire on action class.

FILE : **displayTag.jsp**

```
<display:table name="list1" sort="list" size="20" pagesize="5" id="table1" export="true" requestURI="" partialList="true">
        <display:column property="no" group="1" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"></display:column>
        <display:column property="nam" group="2" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"></display:column>
        <display:column property="ct" group="3" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" autolink="true"></display:column>
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="diplayTag.xls"></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="diplayTag.pdf"></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="diplayTag.csv"></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true"></display:setProperty>
</display:table>
```

I use `request.setAttribute("list1", li);` where i set all data in `list1(ArrayList)` and pass to the **displayTag.jsp.**

DisplayTag get all data and display in the table format. But my need is to pass only 5 data at a time and on clicking next page action class send other 5 data and so on.

I refer link : [Display tag pagination problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888367/display-tag-pagination-problem)

But i can not understand because i'm use MySql and also new on DisaplyTag.

DB : *MySql*

Framework : *struts2*

Answer (score 0):

After researching and hard working i found answer.

FILE : **displayTag.jsp**

```
<display:table name="list1" sort="external" size="20" pagesize="5" id="table1" export="true" requestURI="disTag" partialList="true">
     // code as above
</dispaly:table>
```

here `requestURI="disTag"` is a action name.

FILE : **struts.xml**

```
<action name="disTag" class="className">
    <result name="success">/displayTag.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

FILE : **class file**

```
page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter((new ParamEncoder("table1").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_PAGE))));
if(page != 0)
{
    start = (page - 1) * 5;   //5 is row or data per page.
}
getData(start, 5);    //getData is a method which store all data in ArrayList. Based on start index.
```