# set Display tags pagination to fetch results from session

Tags: jquery, hibernate, pagination, displaytag

This is a theoretical question so im not posting any code here.

The question is.. I'm using display tags to fetch results for a report from multiple tables having 20 million rows at least. The query takes its own sweet time to execute and display tags do a fine job of rendering the table. There could be a thousand results but I display only 10 per page. Every time I hit the next page, it goes to my dao class and fetches the same result set again even though the results are already in the session for the next page. Now in this scenario, my question is two fold.

a) Is there any way I can make it look into the session for the second third or any consecutive pages?

b) even if the second page gets its results from the second page, the first time the query gets executed takes time. Is there any way to cut down this time?

I already referred to the below questions to have an idea. I'm looking for more ideas.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770807/displaytag-alternatives
```

I like this one

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143408/displaytag-pagination-vs-hibernate-pagination/3144744#3144744
```

Comment: How can we improve the performance of the query when we can't see what you have already done.

Comment: dude.. its a stored procedure and its a big ass query.. lets say the query is just select  a,b,c from d,e,f where i.d=j.e and so on..now what? my main problem is with the display tags giving me an option to paginate.. every time i use pagination option.. the query runs again.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in displaytag that says, "go back to the DAO class".  All it does it re-request the page with some special query parameters that tell it what slice of the results to show you.  What happens when the page is requested is completely up to you.

All you have to do is in your request handler, see if the results are stored on the session.  If they are, then use those results in the response.  If they aren't, then run your query and store them on the session before returning the response.

Of course, if the user is allowed to specify parameters you'll need to know what parameters were used to generate the results stored on the session so you know if you need to re-run the query or not.

And then there is the question of whether you really want to (or can) store 20+ million rows in memory.

Answer (score 0):

you can check using some parameters which display tag give.
This is the way i use to check........

```
Map stockParamMap = WebUtils.getParametersStartingWith(httpServletRequest, "d-");
if (stockParamMap.size() == 0) { 
     //dao call goes here    
WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(httpServletRequest, "display_tbl",
                    list);     // set list in session
}
```

If there is no parameter contains "d-" in your url only then it will call dao.Otherwise it populate the list in session only. While doing paginations it will contain this parameter so it wont call dao again. 
Hope it will help you