# Displaytag, Search Filter and Pagination

Tags: java, jsp, pagination, displaytag

I need some help with DisplayTable. I use Spring Framework, so my Table is in a JSP, the List is send by my controller. I have a displaytable with pagination that work perfectly, but I'd like to add a Search Filter to search in this Table.
But, the problem is that it's search only in the current page. 
I found the JQuery QuickSearch, and it's work but only if I display all the list in the same page, and with the pagination, only the current page is searched :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id_search").quicksearch("table tbody tr", {
                noResults: '#noresults',
                stripeRows: ['odd', 'even'],
                loader: 'span.loading'
            });
        });
```

And in the JSP :

```
<form action="#">
        Rechercher dans la liste : <input type="text" name="search" value="" id="id_search" placeholder="Rechercher" autofocus />
    </form>
```

I must use pagination because I have lot of entries (250+). The Sort function work good and sort all pages but not the search filter.
Do you have any idea in how I can do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343993/display-tag-issues-with-pagination-and-sorting?rq=1